# MPDF can't load after change site url

Tags: mpdf

I was using MPDF without problem, for some reason I had to change my site url. After doing that change MPDF can't load , i have this error :

```
Message: Undefined index: port

 Filename: src/Mpdf.php

Line Number: 11944
File: /home/admedica/public_html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php
 Line: 11944
Function: _error_handler
```

I'am using 7.1.1

May I know the reason for which it stops loading ?
Thanks

Comment: May anyone please give an idea of the reason it happened ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an unhandled array key from `parse_url` in mPDF which is fixed in just released version 7.1.6. Upgrade and the error should disappear. If not, file an issue in [mPDF Github issue tracker](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues).

Also see https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/870

Comment: I found the problem. The problem is after I changed my domain name, i should let time passing until it gets propagated. Once the domain name is ok, the mPDF start back to work as it was. Thank you guy for support.